# Using the contents of a cell to act as a range in VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

**I AM USING GOOGLE SHEETS, NOT SURE IF THIS IS THE BEST PLACE TO POST BUT FOR CLARIFICATION!**

Hi there, I am attempting to index the contents of a cell and use that as the range in my VLOOKUP formula.

The formula is

> =VLOOKUP(B4,'B2'!1:130,2,FALSE)

Explaining the formula...
The search key is the Employee Name which comes from a dropdown in B4.
The Range is B2, which is a dropdown for my four sheet names (Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4)
The idea is to index column 2 in the sheet value of B2 (test1,2,3 or 4) and return the result of Sam (employee name).

Every time I try, it returns 'Unresolved sheet name B2.

I have tried using INDEX(B4) in replacement of B4 but still no luck. Attached is a photo for reference.

[image: Photo Reference]

Answer (score 0):

*it returns 'Unresolved sheet name B2.*

This is because you don't have a sheet named "B2". You are actually trying to refer to the sheet named "Test1" which is the value in *cell B2*.

There's also a slight problem with the `VLOOKUP` range of "1:130" - normally this range will include the column references as well.

The solution is to use a combination of `ADDRESS` (which will allow you to use the value in Cell B2 as the 'Sheet name') and `INDIRECT` (which will convert the string created by `ADDRESS` into a cell reference).

**ADDRESS**

- Enter this in Cell D1: `=address(1,1,4,1,B2)`

  - The result will be as string - "Test1!A1"
- Enter this in Cell D2: `=address(10,4,4)`

  - The result will be a string - "D10"
- Combine them in Cell D3: `=address(1,1,4,1,B2)&":"&address(10,4,4)`

  - The result is a string - "Test1!A1:D10"

**COMBINE INDIRECT WITH VLOOKUP**

- Enter this in Cell C6: `=vlookup(B4,indirect(address(1,1,4,1,B2)&":"&address(10,4,4)),2,0)`
- The result will be the value in the column B of sheet="Test1", the cell directly adjacent to the value = "Sam"

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: result]

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it should be as simple as this:

`=VLOOKUP(B4,INDIRECT(B2&"!A:B"),2,FALSE)`

... or if you are going to be requesting other info from the row...

`=VLOOKUP(B4,INDIRECT(B2&"!1:130"),2,FALSE)`